# Reg hosting php mysql application in windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Our application is developed using PHP 5.2.14 and MySQL 5.1.41. One of our client wanted to host this in windows Azure.

We searched and understand from below links that we can host php application in cloud.

Host PHP in the Cloud with Windows Azure -
   http://www.sitepoint.com/windows-azure-php/

Migrating from MySQL to SQL Azure Using SSMA - 
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/03/23/migrating-from-mysql-to-sql-azure-using-ssma.aspx

We did not done this before. Please advise to proceed in a right way. Please advise what are the issues will come

Thanks

Comment: Try [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

The usual route is this :

1/ Migrate your application to PHP 5.3

PHP 5.2 is deprecated and although it can run on Azure you'll be on your own when you encounter issues..

2/ Migrate the data to Sql Azure

The migration assistant is one way to go. Notice that Visual Studio 11 beta can update a lot of things on your Sql Azure Schema without loosing your data, so you may consider installing that as well.

3/ Update your code to use php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll or php_sqlsrv.dll

do NOT use the old mssql drivers for this. When you try to connect to your Sql Azure database don't forget that the user is really username@machine and not simply username

4/ Deploy to Azure

Once you have done all these on your local machine (you'll connect to Sql Azure from your dev box), you'll begin deploying to Azure. Don't do it before, you'll just waste your time.

5/ Fix extensions and permissions issues

6/ Replace local storage with blob storage or Azure storage when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The link you talks about using eclispe plugin for deploying PHP application to Windows Azure. This plugin is very old and not based on Full IIS support in Windows Azure Web role. Now you should use Windows Azure SDK for PHP to package and deploy PHP application to Windows Azure. Please refer following link for details:

http://phpazure.codeplex.com
http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/packaging-applications

### regards,

Satish